# Como borro un archivo sin usar id

Tags: angular7

```
Intento borrar un archivo (Angular 7) y uso 2 formas, 
una funciona, la otra no. Alguien me puede ayudar ?

    Este sistema funciona
           deleteProductArbyId(id:number):Observable<void> {
              if (!id) {return}
              return this.http.delete<void>(`${ubi}/${id}`, httpOptions).pipe(
                tap(() => console.log('Ade/id=' + id)),
                catchError(this.handleError)
              );
            }
    Este sitema NO funciona (Error 404), pero necesito ESTE !! 
            deleteProductArbyIndx(pIndexf:string):Observable<void> {
              if (!pIndexf) {return}
              let headers = new HttpHeaders();
              let params  = new HttpParams().set('indx', pIndexf);
              return this.http.delete<void>(`${ubi}`,{params, headers}).pipe(
                tap(() => console.log('Ade/idx=' + pIndexf)),
                catchError(this.handleError)
              );
            }
```

esta respuesta obtengo:
DELETE /Archivos?indx=sgmxb5dpft&Action=completed 404

Necesito encontrar el archi via clave indx.
Gracias por su tiempo !